# Properly retrieve username and useful values (site title, copyright, etc.)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pubnub

I have a simple web app based on this project ( https://github.com/arthurkao/angular-drywall ), running with NodeJS and AngularJS as the front-end.

I'm trying to set up a simple page that displays a list of all connected users on a map (using Google Maps, Geolocation and PubNub).

Here's how I'm actually doing it:

```
angular.module('base').controller('TravelCtrl',
  function($rootScope, $scope, NgMap, security, $geolocation, PubNub){

    $rootScope.extusers = []; //remote users

    $scope.initTravel = function() { //declare the init function

      PubNub.init({
        subscribe_key: $rootScope.security.keys.psk,
        publish_key: $rootScope.security.keys.ppk,
        uuid: $rootScope.security.currentUser.username,
        ssl: true
      });

      PubNub.ngSubscribe({
        channel: "travel",
        state: {
          position: {},
        }
      });

      console.log("Loaded Travel");

      $geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
        timeout: 60000
      }).then(function(position) { //when location is retreived

        $scope.position = position;

        PubNub.ngSubscribe({
          channel: "travel",
          state: {
            position: {
              lat: Math.floor($scope.position.coords.latitude*1000)/1000, //decrease accuracy
              long: Math.floor($scope.position.coords.longitude*1000)/1000,
            },
          }
        });

        $rootScope.$on(PubNub.ngPrsEv("travel"), function(event, payload) {
          $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.extusers = PubNub.ngPresenceData("travel");
          });
        });

        PubNub.ngHereNow({ channel: "travel" });

        $scope.showInfo = function(evt, marker) { //show user window on map

          $scope.extuser = marker;

          $scope.showInfoWindow('infoWindow');

        };
      });
    };

    if ($rootScope.hasLoaded()) { //if username and keys are already loaded, then init module
      $scope.initTravel();
    } else { //else, wait for username and keys to be loaded
      $rootScope.$on('info-loaded', function(event, args) {
        $scope.initTravel();
      });
    }

  }
);
```

Although it works, it seems like it's very buggy and only loads sometimes. Occasionally, I get this:

[Result screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/80515e7d5bcabb1dd62433199aa13185.png)

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, as I simply followed the tutorials on PubNub's AngularJS SDK.

I think this has to do with how I'm initialising the application.

```
angular.module('app').run(['$location', '$rootScope', 'security', function($location, $rootScope, security) {
    // Get the current user when the application starts
    // (in case they are still logged in from a previous session)
    $rootScope.hasLoaded = function() {
      return (security.keys && security.info && security.currentUser); //check if everything is loaded correctly
    };

    $rootScope.checkLoading = function() {
      if ($rootScope.hasLoaded()) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('info-loaded'); //broadcast event to "TravelCtrl" in order to init the module
      }
    };

    security.requestKeys().then($rootScope.checkLoading); //request secret keys

    security.requestSiteInfo().then($rootScope.checkLoading); //then templating info (site title, copyright, etc.)

    security.requestCurrentUser().then($rootScope.checkLoading); //and finally, current user (name, id, etc.)

    $rootScope.security = security;

    // add a listener to $routeChangeSuccess
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
      $rootScope.title = current.$$route && current.$$route.title? current.$$route.title: 'Default title';
    });
}]);
```

1- Request secret keys, site info and current user with JSON API.

2- Wait until everything's loaded then init the application with the appropriate keys (PubNub, Google Maps)

--
My question is:
How do you instantiate an AngularJS app after retrieving useful information via a RESTful API?

I'm pretty new to AngularJS, and I wouldn't be surprised if my approach is totally ridiculous, but I really need to get some advice on this.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Ulysse

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to wait that the AJAX Query ended to initate the angular APPs.
you can use the $http promise ( [details her](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) )

In the controller :

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available

    // data is now accessible in the html
    $scope.data = response ; 
    // you can call a function to add markers on your maps with the received data
    addMarkerOnMap(response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

You can also add a watch on some variable to wait modification on them :

```
// you should have $scope.yourVarName declared. 
$scope.$watch('yourVarName', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log(newValue);
});
```

Or watch a list/object

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[var1,var2]', function () {

},true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alainlb! I believe I already have the promise part working, which corresponds to security.requestKeys() in my code (this is handled by the security module).
The fact is, I really need to have everything loaded before initialising my application (as you can see, I need to provide user information in PubNub.ngSuscribe). Will it work?

Comment: You are wright. security.requestKeys() return a promise you use with then(). you can call a function in the then to be called when the promise is resolved